# How do I apply a regex on a Parenthesized Substring Matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an HTML content and I do this to get the Textual content .

```
string='<img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image">Randomz is the name of the image</img><img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image">Randomz is the name of the image</img><img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image">Randomz is the name of the image</img><img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image">Randomz is the name of the image</img>'
re=(/([<][^<]+>)([^<]+)([<][^<]+>)/g);
newstr=string.replace(re,"$1$2$3");
```

This give me back the original string.

My problem is that I need to apply another `string.replace(regex,$2)` before `newstr=string.replace(re,"$1$2$3"`)

That is, I need to apply another regex on the parametrized catch before applying the final solution.

Comment: Need not always be img tags , could be anything . Further my problem is to replace only the textual contents and keep the order intact .

Comment: Your example uses child text nodes and closing tags for an element that can not have child nodes or closing tags.

Comment: Never use RegExp to parse HTML! It seems you already got an error there, shouldn't it be `<[^>]+>` (or just `<.+?>`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing here, but I guess you're looking for `replace` callbacks:

```
string='<img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image">Randomz is the name of the image</img><img src="Random'
re=(/([<][^<]+>)([^<]+)([<][^<]+>)/g);
newstr=string.replace(re, function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
     $2 = do_something_with($2);
     return $1 + $2 + $3;
});
```

As a side note, regular expressions is not the best tool for html transformations.

Comment: Precisely that , thanks . This is a simple hack for a clean HTML code . I understand its not good for HTML transformation .

Comment: @Nishant - Make sure you change `[^<]` to `[^>]` in your first and third groups. It will NOT work properly otherwise. If you apply the above code to a document with several HTML elements, and examine what's coming back in $1, $2, etc., you'll see what I mean.